# How to revert "git rm" of an untracked file

Tags: git

I'm facing a situation where I have accidentally done a `git rm foo.c` before committing it even once. So, it was **completely untracked** by git and yet the file was physically deleted.
I have already tried `git reset --hard` and `git checkout .`, but they both don't seem to work.

Any suggestions before I restart the arduous task of rewriting that file?

Comment: Did you ever happen to stash it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a file is not tracked, git can't help you. That's the only requirement git has: you need to track files. It's not git's mission to watch ("track") untracked files.

You need to recover your file with some other method.

Comment: Agreed.But then why did git physically delete the file if it was not tracking it. That's my only issue.

Comment: Well, you tell'd git to remove a file.... and it's a pleasure for git to work as you expected.

Comment: Sigh ! You are right. No point wasting time over spilt milk. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

May be try [gitjk](https://github.com/mapmeld/gitjk) or [recuva](http://alternativeto.net/software/recuva/) first before rewriting it.